# How to schedule frequent background jobs with support above Nougat?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I'm making an app that needs to frequently query a server for updates. I've tried jobScheduler, but since Nougat, their frequency is limited to 15 minute or more intervals. Also, according to this site https://medium.com/til-kotlin/jobintentservice-for-background-processing-on-android-o-39535460e060, Oreo now kills long-running background processes after a few minutes. The only feasible solution I've found is using firebase, but it costs $25/month for over 100 users, and I assume would cut out any devices without play services. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wound up using Firebase. The simple message sending features are free to use, which I didn't realize originally. Works well, and not too hard to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Add a scheduler job.scheduler job will help you in this execution

Comment: I tried that, but since Nougat, it "clamps" it to 15 minutes. If you try anything more frequent than that, it defaults to 15 minutes.